# The issue with construction : make + noun

Tags: idioms, idiom-request

Is there any avalaible list of nouns related with "make" where "make" doesn't mean "make" in the sentence.

e.g. I have made the plane .  /  I managed to catch the plane.

Comment: What you're asking for are idioms with the verb "make". Try googling "idiomatic use of make", "idioms with make", "idioms that use make", and you will find pages like [this one](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/make). I hope my advice helps you *make headway* in your quest.

Comment: 1+ for the link to TFD which has a list of more than 100 collocations with to make. See also TFD to make in dictionary.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a list question, and should be answerable using a dictionary.

Comment: Meaning is context-dependent. *I have made the plane* can have all kinds of different meanings; even if we establish *plane* as referring to a fixed-wng aircraft, *made* could still mean to have physically constructed it, to have arrived in time for a scheduled use of it, to have attained a qualification to use it, to have been the one most influential in its regard, to have sighted it from a distance, to have acted like a plane, and so on. The more meanings a verb has, the more important context is; *make* is a big one, but also consider *do*, *get*, *have*, and their ilk.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for alternative definitions of make.

[Dictionary.com defines make](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/make?o=100074) with a couple definitions that apply to yours:

> to cause to be or become; render: *to make someone happy.*
>   to appoint or name: *The president made her his special envoy.*
>   to cause, induce, or compel: *to make a horse jump a barrier.*
>   to estimate; reckon: *to make the distance at ten miles.*
>   to arrive in time for: *to make the first show.*
>   to receive mention or appear in or on: *The robbery made the front page.*
>   *slang* to recognize or identify: *Any cop in town will make you as soon as you walk down the street.*
>   to cause oneself, or something understood, to be as specified: *to make sure.*

There are some others, but I don't think it would be useful to list... all of them... the link provided will let you make your own decision to what counts on the list. If you check other dictionaries, you'll find the definitions differ slightly and that may help flesh out your list.

Make is a very versatile word. You'd have an easier time making a more complete list with *shoe* or something... :-)

Comment: I mean to have more examples as .Make plane. Where make doesnt mean make

Comment: Sorry, an unending list of examples isn't really what Stack Exchange is for. I think the information in this answer should give you the stepping stones you need to craft your own sentences based on the (over 60!) definitions in the dictionary link.